# Debugging TypeScript Node.js Compilation Error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, debugging, ts-node

I am trying to setup a debugging environment on an 2019 project so I added the following script to my `package.json`

```
"dev:debug": "tsc-watch --onFirstSuccess \"node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/app.ts\"",
```

Running it would give me the following

```
> node-api-starter@1.0.0 start:dev D:\p\my-project
> tsc-watch --onFirstSuccess "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/app.ts"

7:18:10 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode... 


7:18:27 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/b9a130c4-473d-4b55-a512-50ae9cff15a3
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:423
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/api/auth/auth.controller.ts:580:29 - error TS2339: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

580     user.refreshToken = req.auth.refreshToken; 
                                ~~~~
src/api/auth/auth.controller.ts:581:23 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

581     user.userId = req.user.id;
                          ~~~~
src/api/auth/auth.controller.ts:617:82 - error TS2339: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

617     const user = await userService.getUserInfoByCustomColumn("refreshToken", req.auth.refreshToken);

                                  ~~~~
src/api/auth/auth.controller.ts:782:76 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

782     const user = await userService.getUserInfoByCustomColumn("userId", req.user.id, true);        

                            ~~~~
src/api/auth/auth.controller.ts:800:46 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

800     await userService.updateUserPassword(req.user.id, insertedNewPassword);
                                                 ~~~~

    at createTSError (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:423:12)
    at reportTSError (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:427:19)
    at getOutput (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:554:36)
    at Object.compile (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:760:32)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:839:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\p\my-project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:842:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Example of one error

```
auth.controller.ts - Line 577

const refresh = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const user = new User();
    user.refreshToken = req.auth.refreshToken;
    ...
}
```

`Request` being a part of the Express library

```
    interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary> extends core.Request<P> { }
```

There are 2 files that declare `Express` namespace and export `Request` interfaces with different varibales (see below)

`request.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user?: any;
    auth?: any;
  }
}
```

`declarations.d.ts`

```
declare module 'draftjs-to-html';

declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    availableCountries: number[];
    language: string;
    pagination: {
      pageSize: number;
      pageNumber: number;
    };
  }
}
```

So what happens here is that the first compilation using `tsc-watch` is done successfully but then some errors in the project pop up.

- Does that mean that `ts-node` tries to recompile ?
- If so, why does it fail? does it compile with a different configuration than `tsc-watch`?
- Is there a flag that I could use to skip checking these errors

Comment: Can you show the relevant code and the types `Request<T>` and `ParamsDictionary`

Comment: @MikeS. Just updated the description, `Request` is basically the standard Express `Request`

Comment: Well, is it right? Or is there a property `auth` on type `Request<ParamsDictionary>`

Comment: Actually there is a `request.d.ts` file with the content declaring the namespace Express and adds `user` and `auth` to its `Request` interface. Also there's another file called `declarations.d.ts` which does exactly the same thing but for different variables. (Added their contents to the description).

Answer (score 0):

First, `ts-node` rebuilds your sources, so you do the compilation job twice. Not sure if the problem is caused by it, maybe `ts-node` is unable to locate your `tsconfig`.

As an immediate fix I'd suggest [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) the existing `express.Request` declaration, whatever it is in your case, with your own. Basically, you put that declaration from `request.d.ts` somewhere in your source code where it is available for your controller functions and update with proper types where needed (or roll with `any`):

```js
declare global {
    export namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            user?: any;
            auth?: {refreshToken: string};
        }
    }
}
```

Now `Request` sports a properly typed `refreshToken`.

Comment: Thank you for the TypeScript fix suggestions. We ended up using nodemon without ts-node. I am still not getting why ts-node couldn't locate the the same tsconfig. But that's a subject for the summer :)